# Encountered null value trying to display a list item in widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm a newbie to flutter.I just stumbled upon an issue while working with lists. So, I have a list of values and a ListView.builder() to output those values in a Card view for each item. Doing so, I get null value in the Card but when I try to print it, it produces the right output. I was wondering if you can help me figuring this out. Thanks in advance!

For simplification, I have only provided a sample code.

```
List<Fruit>  fruits = [Fruit(item:'Apple'),Fruit(item:'Orange'),Fruit(item:'Grapes'),Fruit(item:'Banana'),];


Widget build(BuildContext context) {
print('${fruits.item}');
return Container(
  child: CustomCard(
  context: context,
  value: fruits.items,));}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure when you're building your list that you only pass in one item at a time to the itemBuilder.

Here is a link to a good article for using ListView.builder(): 
https://medium.com/@DakshHub/flutter-displaying-dynamic-contents-using-listview-builder-f2cedb1a19fb

Here is some code that should work for what you're trying to accomplish:

```
class MyList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> fruits = ["apple", "orange", "grapes"];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: fruits.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return CustomCard(fruit: fruits[index]);
      },
    );
  }
}

class CustomCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final String fruit;
  CustomCard({this.fruit});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: Text(fruit),
    );
  }
}
```